# Extracting sass file from Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

**Introduction**

We have an ionic application which is used by 20+ clients (B2B). Every client could determine which 'theming' they wanted and we would change the color of the sass variables accordingly (every client has a separate build application, the base is the same, just different namespace .. within app store).

Now some rules in Apple guidelines changed plus we are getting to a point where maintaining 20+ apps is becoming undoable. We, therefore, decided to go to one app where we could also allow them to change the 'theme' at runtime instead of compile time.

Our solution for this was to have a base theme that would be set at compile time, and at runtime, we would consume a Rest Service returning the compiled sass file with the correct theming. To do this we would require the 'original' sass file so that we can change the theme colors when the service is called.

**Question**

Is there a way to get the concatenated sass file in ionic before it is sent through the sass compiler?